# prevent scrolling to top when clicking on <li> in jquery mobile with phonegap

Tags: ios, listview, jquery-mobile

when i click on list view items with anchor href="#" or href="", the screen goes back to the top.

And it's very annoying when i have to scroll down where there are overflowing list item like the one below.

Is there any way to prevent this scrolling to top issue?

```
<ul data-role="listview">
   <li> Item1 </li>
   <li> Item2 </li>
   <li> Item3 </li>
   <li> Item4 </li>
   <li> Item5 </li>
   <li> Item6 </li>
   <li> Item7 </li>
   ... 
   <li> Item20 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you mean when you press an li, the page advances to the next screen and when you go back it's scrolled back up to the top?

Comment: ur question cleared up my question.. i realized that i shouldn't put <a> when href="" or href="#" inside <li>.. but what I still need to solve is that, when i 'touch' on <li> while scrolling down, the page advances to the next screen when i intended to just scroll down.